# How does this oscillator work under a constant DC voltage?

Tags: oscillator, tank

Consider:

[image: Circuit]

How does the oscillator in this circuit work? A tank circuit can't oscillate when there is a constant DC voltage, am I wrong? I simulated the circuit in [NI Multisim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NI_Multisim) and couldn't observe any oscillation. But the circuit works pretty well in real life.

Please help me understand how do this and how the negative feedback work.

Comment: Where did the circuit come from? What explanation came with the circuit? What have you uncovered so far about colpitts oscillators? Have you tried leaving your sim running for tens of milli seconds because oscillators are not always instant starters.

Comment: There wasn't much explanation for the oscillator part. I can see how colpitts oscillators work, but I can't understand how this one oscillates. Besides, as far as i know colpitts oscillators have 2 capacitors parallel to an inductor. My circuit doesn't much resemble those colpitts oscillators.
Yes I did wait. All I saw in the oscillator tool was a constant 9V line, as I would expect.

Answer (score 14):

In real life, an oscillator will start up by amplifying transistor/resistor noise, and/or from the circuit power-on transient.

In a simulator, noise may well be absent in a simple transistor model, and the initial DC bias point analysis will leave all the components with nice quiescent voltages on them. The transistor will then just sit there amplifying nothing into nothing.

The easiest way to kick an oscillator into life is to use the simulator's initial conditions control on one of the capacitors in the tank circuit. This means that the AC simulation will start with something other than 'nothing' to amplify.

Most simulators have a way of setting the voltage on a capacitor to a specific value, either a 'use initial conditions' checkbox in the component dialogue, or a text directive included in the circuit. Read the manual for your simulator. If it doesn't have initial conditions, then switch to a better simulator. LTSpice is good, if clunky, and comes at the right price.

Answer (score 9):

The oscillator works because of the feedback path provided by C5.  Note that this is positive feedback, one of the criteria for oscillation.  When the collector goes low, the emitter is brought lower.  At a fixed base voltage, this causes more base current, which drives the collector even lower.  This configuration is common enough to have its own name, which is *Colpitts oscillator*.

The C4-L1 tank circuit ensures that the Q2 stage only has gain at a narrow frequency range, which is tuned by adjusting C4.

I considered the base voltage constant when analyzing how the oscillator works.  It is actually varying as a function of the microphone signal.  However, that is much lower frequency than the RF oscillations.  The base voltage therefore changes very slowly relative to the RF frequency, so can be thought of as constant over individual RF cycles.

Comment: I can see how colpitts oscillators work, but I can't understand how this one oscillates. Besides, as far as i know colpitts oscillators have 2 capacitors parallel to an inductor. My circuit doesn't much resemble those colpitts oscillators. I built the same oscillator in an online simulator. Here is the result: [image](http://i.imgur.com/tL7bFuu.png)
The graph at the left side is the capacitance of the C4, and the other graph shows the current across the L1. As you can see the current never changes direction.

Comment: I noticed that as the capacitor discharges, the current across the inductor slightly (like 0.01mA) increases, and when the capacitor starts to recharge the current slightly decreases. Is this the oscillation i am looking for?

Comment: @Nem: Try real parts.  Oscillators require some noise to start up, which simulations may not provide.

Comment: @Nemesis Alternatively, you can set the initial condition in your simulator (i.e. the initial voltage across C4 or C5, or the initial current through L1). This should also work to start the oscillations in the simulator with ideal circuit elements.